# Execution seemingly halts for no reason when using Dictionary.add within a foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is really puzzling me as I can't figure out any apparent reason for execution of my method to come to a sudden halt.

The method I have below is relatively simple, all I am doing is iterating through a collection of objects and adding some data to a new Dictionary based on the current data.

```
public Dictionary<string, string> MapValidationErrorToIdentifiers(List<ErrorField> errors)
        {
            var mappings = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            foreach (var error in errors)
            {
                string identifier;
                if (error.CollectionIndex == "")
                {
                    identifier = error.Section + "-" + error.FieldName.Replace(" ", "-");
                }
                else
                {
                    identifier = error.Section + "-" + (error.CollectionIndex + 1) + "-" + error.FieldName.Replace(" ", "-");
                }
                identifier = identifier.ToLower();
                mappings.Add(identifier, error.Message);
            }

            return mappings;
        }
```

The input object `List<ErrorField>`, is comprised of `ErrorField` objects, which are simple DTO objects.

```
public class ErrorField
    {
        public string FieldName { get; set; }
        public string Section { get; set; }
        public string CollectionIndex { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
```

During testing of this method in one instance the `errors` input object contained 12 `ErrorField` objects, the foreach completed one iteration successfully, and a key-value pair was added to the dictionary. Then on the second iteration the method worked up until the `mappings.Add(identifier, error.Message);` call, at which point the debugger stops entirely and no further execution occurs.

The strange thing here is that execution just stops, no exceptions or errors are thrown. This method is part of a larger ASP.NET project, and this method is used within a controller. When the execution halts it causes my end-point to return 404. Not sure if that is relevant or not.

Comment: Add() probably throws because the same key is already present, with the exception bring caught by code higher up. Enable first-chance exceptions during debugging to catch it.

Comment: When you say execution stops, do you mean the program shuts down, or that it is hanging, not getting anywhere?

Comment: @CodeCaster This is exactly what it was. I enabled all exceptions and the exception appeared. Thanks!